# JAVA Byte Manipulation

Tags: java, byte

I want to read a binary file and do some manipulation on each byte. I want to test that I am manipulating the bytes correctly. I want to set a byte variable1 to "00000000" and then another byte variable2 set at "00001111" and OR them newvariable = variable1|variable2, shift the newvariable << 4 bits and then print out the int value.

```
 byte a = 00000000;
 //Convert first oneByte to 4 bits and then xor with a;
 byte b = 00001111;
 byte c = (byte)(a|b);
 c = c << 4;
 System.out.println("byte= " + c + "\n");
```

I am not sure why I keep getting "incompatiable types:possible lossy conversion from byte to int"

Comment: You can read this too https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a '0b' in front of those numbers to express binary constants. The number 00001111 is interpreted as a literal in octal, which is 585 in decimal. The max byte is 127 (since it's signed).  Try `0b00001111` instead.

As literals, those will still be `int`, so depending on where you do the assignment, you may also need to explicitly cast down to `byte`.

Comment: Adding '0b' infront of byte a and byte b fixes it there . Then settingbyte c = (byte)(c << 4); even if casting it by c = c (byte) << 4 works printing -16 as expected!

Comment: `00001111` is 1111 in octal and 585 in decimal

Comment: @saka1029 Good catch. Updating my answer.